# how to check if elements from a database exist in a array listview android

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have a list of arrays . I need to go through it and see if there is an element given at input. How to do this?

```
DatabaseUtil dbUtil1 = new DatabaseUtil(this);
        dbUtil1.open();
        Boolean contain=false;
        Cursor cursor = dbUtil1.fetchAllElements();
        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Model s= new Model(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2));


                if (list.contains(s)) //THIS DOES NOT WORK
                {
                    contain=true;
                }
                else 
                    {
                    list.add(get(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2)));
                    }

            }
        }

        dbUtil1.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your instance a new object.... 
add your created object in your else like this:

```
            Model s= new Model(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2));


            if (list.contains(s)) //THIS DOES NOT WORK
            {
                contain=true;
            }
            else 
            {
                list.add(s);
            }
```

Comment: the problem is the fact that I do have the s object in my list but it but it still goes on else method. It's like it doesn t see the object in mylist of elements